# Get files path from html website on android

Tags: javascript, android, web

I am trying to create a website to let the user upload a directory or multiple files to a server. One of my requirements is to send file attributes (like file path, file modification time, also tried to create time but didn’t find any solution to this) to the server.
I am using chrome browser on both computer and android.

I created a form in HTML like this (only the relevant code)

```
<input type="file" name="files" webkitdirectory multiple/>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
```

It works well on the computer but when I tried to do it on my android device I couldn’t upload a directory but only files, but when I upload using the files input I don’t receive the file path.

How can I upload a directory also in android?

Comment: I used chrome in both cases

Comment: I already updated it, can you please answer my question?

Comment: I moved it to the start. do you know how can I solve my issue?

Comment: Chrome==chrome ?